# NodeJS - Deploy to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue-cli-3

I completed an independent and basic project which is about Edit Distance Algorithm. Need a deployment environment for demo to show off some people. I've got 2 app API + Client in GitHub Repo. How could I deploy to Heroku ?

https://github.com/burakkaanerce/editdistance-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has very good [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) for deploying Node.js application in its platform. Kindly go through it and raise a question, if you are struck in the midway.

If Vue + Express is your concern, this [article](https://medium.com/@Dongmin_Jang/nodejs-express-vue-heroku-d3ed48edee0c) might help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't notice any doc for my problem. I need 2 terminal to start for 2 servers in my local. This is my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It says "~/app/express-app >DEBUG=myapp:* npm start"

What does it mean ? myapp

Comment: myapp is your express app. In your context, it is api.

Comment: I did every step but when I was trying to connect localhost:4000, It directed to classic API (Cannot GET /)

Comment: solved the situation, resetting express was solved and now I'll deploy to heroku. thank you dude.